# Can I distribute the Google TTS Engine with offline data on my device?

Tags: licensing, software

My company would like to distribute devices containing preinstalled Google Text-to-Speech (TTS) engine, together with some downloaded offline voice data.

Can we do this without the need to acquire any additional licenses/permissions?

My findings in this matter are insufficient, but I'm going to present them here anyway, to avoid confusion:

- Android TTS framework is a part of Android Open Source Project,
  licensed under the terms of Apache 2.0 license, making it perfect for
  free distribution
- The framework allows multiple TTS engines,
  including Google TTS, which comes as a part of the operating system
  installed by devices' OEM.
- As far, as I understand, the usage of
  Google TTS is governed by Google Terms of Service, which does not say
  much about preinstalling parts of otherwise available online Google
  software or its data On my device
- As a user, I can go to Settings and download any of the available Google languages for offline use.

Comment: This is a fun one... I'm not familiar at all with android development, but I would assume that if something is built in, then it's available for your use. The terms of service likely generally applies to users of the end application. How do you use the TTS (Sorry, I don't know what that is...)? Also, do you have a link to those terms and conditions? That might give some insight :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 Here is a link to Google Terms and Conditions: https://www.google.com/policies/terms/
TTS is a library that allows other applications (including the ones we make) to transform written text to speech.

Comment: IANAL, but I don't see any problem with what you're trying to do. I assume this is like setting-up the device before being distributed, which you have access to the feature publicly.

Comment: That's not clear from the details provided and why not ask Google?